# Get.changeTheme does not work on real Device

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I'm trying to change theme dynamically using GetX library., it works perfectly on iOS simulator, but it does not work on real device.

I'm using this code:

```
Get.changeTheme(AppThemes.darkTheme);
```

darkTheme is the custom theme I want to switch to.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved GetX dynamic change theme issue by referencing **ThemeMode** as per code below instead of the GetX code sample using **ThemeData**.

In my case this fixed issue where the default device system dark mode would not dynamically update to my ThemeData.light mode.

```
          //Get.changeTheme(Get.isDarkMode ? ThemeData.light() : ThemeData.dark()); //Code from GetX change theme documentation did not work

            Get.changeThemeMode(Get.isDarkMode ? ThemeMode.light : ThemeMode.dark); //Modified successfully by referencing ThemeMode
           setState(() {
           });
```

Comment: This only works in light and dark themes, what if I have multiple themes?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this page because I ran into the exact same problem.

Fortunately, I was able to find a solution: It seems, on a real device, after calling `Get.changeTheme()`, you need to call **`Get.forceAppUpdate()`** to make it count.

Example:

```
Get.changeTheme(buildTheme(value ? Brightness.dark : Brightness.light));
await Get.forceAppUpdate();
```

Comment: I'm trying to use this solution, but not worked for me. Any update about it?